# How to send files to all the connected devices in android using bluetooth?

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth

I created the list that have device detected, and I want to send data to each device; The process is : one device sent data to first device and after disconnect first device and start to connect second device and sent the same data to second device and after disconnect this process until the last device in device list.

So does it possible to do that?

Comment: Refer [this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500212/async-send-to-multiple-clients-and-correct-usage-of-fromasync

Comment: Its very much possible if you find suitable SDKs'.. I have done similar App but the device was a thermal printer...

Comment: @angel but i want to send the file using bluetooth not by socket programming

Comment: @Lucifer  if i try to send a file it give me error as Bluetooth share: File Unknown file not sent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am telling you logic part only, because frankly I haven't done this in Android platform.

1. First Search all the Bluetooth device and collect their UUID and put it in a list.
2. Now in a for look make connection with each device and send the file.

You can not send file to two device at a same time, because Bluetooth Connection is synchronized, so only one connection at a time is allowed.

You can use following code for sending file,

```
BluetoothDevice device; String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/data.txt";  
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)).toString()); 
values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, device.getAddress()); 
values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND); 
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis(); values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts); 
Uri contentUri = getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: please have a look at [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/69d7810f6ef9bb7d)

Comment: @Lucifer what is BluetoothShare what it contain?

Comment: Sorry dear, not much idea about it

Comment: Look at this link http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f7e55d01f9d62254?pli=1   there is a sample application for sending via bluetooth , you can download it for your reference

Comment: here still could not send file

Comment: @ankitmakwana, sorry, i didnt get you

Comment: @ Lucifer in given link demo i checked it in my device but i m just select the image and could not send it to other device

Comment: I suggest you to ask a new question :)

Comment: Hey Guy,

This code is not working for me...
Can anyone give me the correct solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have never done so but reading on different threads on Internet, I found that

You can send data using Bluetooth to multiple device.

For that you will have to connect with each device using different `UUID`.

You can go throught [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/69d7810f6ef9bb7d) to get more understanding.